# Deactivate navigation tab with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have 3 tabs and corresponding panes designed with the Bootstrap.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="tab-A" data-toggle="pill" href="#A" role="tab">tab A</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="tab-B" data-toggle="pill" href="#B" role="tab">tab B</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="tab-C" data-toggle="pill" href="#C" role="tab">tab C</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade border rounded p-3" id="A" role="tabpanel" style="background-color: #CCE5FF;border-radius:25px;">
  pane A
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade border rounded p-3" id="B" role="tabpanel" style="background-color: #CCE5FF;border-radius:25px;">
  pane B
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade border rounded p-3" id="C" role="tabpanel" style="background-color: #CCE5FF;border-radius:25px;">
  pane C
  </div>
</div>
```

Each tab button gets activated when clicked, and previous button gets deactivated. But there is no way to deactivate all buttons. Or at least, I haven't found it yet.

So, I would like to implement switch behaviour to the tab buttons, so that, when clicked, active tab button gets deactivated, and corresponding pane gets hidden.

I have tried this:

```
$('.nav-link').on('click', function (e) {
  var pill = $(this);
  if (pill.hasClass('active')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pill.removeClass('active');
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    var tab = $(id);
    tab.removeClass('active').removeClass('show');
  }
});
```

... but couldn't achieve desired behaviour...

Here is the full sample code https://jsfiddle.net/09Lk2zcp/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to override the bootstrap style :

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Put it after the include of bootstrap